# How to link a JavaScript function to HTML anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to link this JavaScript code to an anchor tag of HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("/brandsOfACategory")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: this.id })
        })
    });
```

**anchor tag**:

`<a id="@c.Key" href ="???" onclick="???">@c.Key</a>`

`brandsOfACategory` action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult brandsOfACategory(string id)
    {
        var result = db.Items.Where(x => x.Category.Name.Equals(id)).Select(x => x.BrandID).ToList();
        var ListOfBrands = db.Brands.Where(t => result.Contains(t.BrandID)).ToList();
        return View(ListOfBrands);
    }
```

`brandsOfACategory.cshtml` is:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineStore.Models.Brand>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Brands in a Category</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach (var i in Model)
    {

        @i.Name.ToString();
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you mean link ?

Comment: I mean `anchor` tag must know where to go when its clicked and as `URL` is given in ajax, browser should display that URL in it once its run.

Comment: then set the `href` value to whatever URL you want to go to.

Comment: but `URL` is only set in the `ajax` call.

Comment: what you mean URL is set in the ajax call ?

Comment: I mean `URL` is set in this line `url: '@Url.Action("/brandsOfACategory")',`

Answer (score 1):

You can write the anchor tag like this-

```
<a id="@c.Key" href ="javascript:void(0);" onclick="postBrands(@c.Key)">@c.Key</a> //replace postBrands with desired function name
```

Then define the function in the javascript which will contain the post request-

```
function postBrands(key) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("/brandsOfACategory")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: key })
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put in href and then fetch the `href` in the client side click code:

```
<a id="@c.Key" href ="@Url.Action("actionName","controllerName")">@c.Key</a>
```

and in the click event you can write following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
    var Url = $(this).attr("href"); // get href value
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: Url, // use it here
        contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: this.id })
    })
```

Comment: Everything is working as expected doing this answer but still getting a 404 error in the browser when `http://localhost:59693/Home/brandsOfACategory` is executing.  I've updated `brandsOfACategory` action method and view codes in the question. While in debug mode, I can see `brandsOfAView` code running as expected with the correct values I need but when its reaching its end, program breaks in the browser displaying a `404 error` i.e., resource not found.

Comment: you need to debug your action code then why it's breaking, check if view exists and is invoked to be rendered

Comment: In debug, I've double checked that action method passing correct list of brands to view. I can clearly see `brandsOfACategory.cshtml` code running as expected. Code is breaking when code finishes and its now time to display the view.

Comment: To explain it in more details: `brandsOfACategory` action method is giving 3 items when anchor tag in the view is clicked i.e., when our `click event` is fired. Now `brandsOfACategory.cshtml` is processing all 3 items received in the list from action method just normal. It is breaking when program completes processing all 3 items in the `brandsOfACategory.cshtml`.

Comment: Inside `Network` tab of Chrome developer tool, following info is showing: `Request URL: http://localhost:59693/Home/brandsOfACategory
Request Method: GET`. Do you think this issue might be due to GET request method?

Comment: if action is called then you need to check your server side code, action and view code

Comment: Like I said, all the server side code is properly running. I've also updated this question with all relevant server side code. I've no clue which server side code I should look into more?

Comment: view code specifically if action does not fails any where

Comment: I think I have somehow declared the view the wrong way.